# Getting an attribute when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get the `rel` attribute when I do click  on a button how this: (targeting with class selector)

```
<button class="nameClass" rel="relName">Content</button>
```

For that I am trying

```
$(".nameClass").click(function(){
    // Here I want to get the rel content of the button that I clicked
})
```

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: `$(this).attr('rel');`

Comment: Look for `jQuery` tutorials and give them a go before trying to work with it. To learn `Javascript` is also essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".nameClass").click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('rel'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nameClass").click(function(){
// Here I want to get the rel content of the button that I clicked
var myRel = $(this).attr('rel');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cqvhyz1/1/)
Attr is used to get values in by supplying key , so u use rel just like attribute "name".

Here you you supply key here its rel , and u get its value.

```
$(".nameClass").on("click",function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('rel'));
})
```